# How to see recently opened files in helm

Tags: helm, history

What's the best way to get the recently opened files in helm. Without helm I just did `C-c C-f` and then `arrow up` to get the  last opened file. And with `M-r` I was  able to to a regexp search through recently opened files. Both doesn't work with helm anymore.

I have

```
(setq helm-ff-file-name-history-use-recentf t)
```

in my `.emacs` file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 15):

Indeed, if `helm-ff-file-name-history-use-recentf` set to true, `helm-find-files` is supposed to use `recentf-list` instead of `file-name-history`.

To enable the recenf minor mode, I have those lines in my init file:

```
; keep a list of recently opened files                                                                      
 (recentf-mode 1)
 (setq-default recent-save-file "~/.emacs.d/recentf")
```

What about `M-x helm-recentf`?

> helm-recentf is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
>   `helm-files.el'.
>
> (helm-recentf)
>
> Preconfigured `helm` for `recentf`.

You may also be interested by [recent files](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles) within Emacs.

Comment: So `helm-find-files` seems to be suposed to provide a history of files anyway (either via `file-name-history` or via `recentf-list`). Both doesn't seem to work for me. `helm-recentf` per se and `helm-mini` works, but that's another thing. Could you add a screenshot of how `helm-find-file` is suposed to display recently opened files (both via `file-name-history` and via `helm-recentf`)? Do I need to press any shortcuts to get it displayed?

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps this isn't quite what you're looking for, but I really like using `helm-mini`, which includes a small browser for recent open files (by calling `helm-recentf` as Nsukami suggests you use).  Here is an example, taken from [this amazing post on helm](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-7):

[image: helm-mini]

Not only does it show all of your open buffers, but it's my most convenient way to view recently opened files. I'd recommend giving it a try!

Comment: Those posts are *farking* great, but can become too daunting for beginners to helm. They are full of plenty good tricks and advices, though they have a steep learning curve and I do not consider them appropriate for a quick hack or solution. I guess **emacs.stackexchange** is in part here to solve that.

Comment: By the way, `helm-mini` is enough for me to answer the question. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There's a `helm-ff-file-name-history` command that displays recently opened files. By default this one is bound to `C-c h` when in `helm-find-files` mode.

Also there is a `C-h m` command that displays help on currently active helm command. You can see key bindings and available commands there.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. This is the correct answer, it deserves more upvotes.